# Update Foreign key table reference after bulk delete/insert?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table A containing parent/child records. I have table B that references Table A. The foreign key is not enforced. I am doing a bulk delete/insert to update the child records to point to the correct parent. This will assign the child records new primary keys which I need to also update in table B.

Is there any way to do this without using a cursor or row by row processing?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that triggers can't be used?  Is your bulk update an unlogged operation?

Comment: its a one time patch script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you post some sample data and how it should be corrected?  Without seeing the actual table schema, I can only makes some assumptions, so this may not work perfectly:

```
select PrimaryKeyField AS RowID, ChildKeyField AS OldChildID, newid() AS NewChildID
into #UpdateTable
from TableA
where SomeConditionToSelectTheChildRecords

update TableA
set TableA.ChildKeyField = #UpdateTable.NewChildID
from TableA
    inner join #UpdateTable on TableA.PrimaryKeyField = #UpdateTable.RowID

update TableB
set TableB.ChildKeyField = #UpdateTable.NewChildID
from TableB
    inner join #UpdateTable on TableB.ChildKeyField = #UpdateTable.OldChildID
```

Comment: Note I am actually deleting the row from Table A, then re-adding it.

Comment: Is there an actual need to delete the rows first?  Seems like you could just update them, or maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem.